# How to delay a signal by D degrees

Tags: sound, delay, allpass

I read in a paper that a sound signal can be delayed by D degrees. How can such a thing be possible? Isn't sound signals expressed only in terms of the time axis?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking about a constant phase shift, i.e. a frequency dependent delay?

Comment: I'm not sure of the terms, but the idea is to change the phase of chirp of a cricket (http://entomology.ifas.ufl.edu/walker/s166p891.pdf)

Comment: In the link you provided, the authors describe the method for generating the signals: " The frequency was maintained at 3.0 Khz... "  So it appears they only wanted to change durations and time delays.  As for the latter, well, there are both analog and digital delay lines. If you google 'time delay beamformer,' you'll get a lot of hits.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the advice and for taking the time for reading the paper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they mean by a delay of $n$ degrees is simply in reference to the periodicity of the chirps. A period consists of the chirp sound plus an interval of silence. Let the period be $T$. If another chirp starts in the middle of the period of the first chirp, i.e. there is an offset of $T/2$, then the authors refer to this as a delay of 180 degrees. So the delay in degrees $\varphi$ is related to the time delay $\tau$ by

$$\varphi=\frac{360^\circ}{T}\tau$$

where $T$ is the period of the chirp.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a finite window of samples of a reasonably band-limited sound signal, you can also represent this sound data in the frequency domain.  In the frequency domain, each frequency point has a phase.

For instance, you can try an fftshift of the data, zero-pad the center of the vector, do an FFT, convert the complex result to magnitude and phase, add a constant to the phase of every bin between DC and Fs/2 (and the inverse constant to the other half so the vector remains conjugate symmetric), then reverse the FFT process to get a phase delayed result.

Added:  It looks like the paper isn't about changing the chirp sound itself, but about changing the timing phase of the start of the chirp sound with reference to an external periodic chirp-rate clock (clock start or mid-clock, etc.). Thus 2 Pi would be equal to one clock period, or 1/chirp_rate.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that you take the DFT of the signal using complex numbers in polar form, that's "magnitude * exp(-j*theta)". And then add a constant C to each phase. How ever how do I know how much the signal would delay in seconds respect to the degrees (in this case radians) added?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have limited number of samples, you can perform a Discrete Fourier Transform and represent your sound in frequency domain (frequencies and phases). After that if you want to apply a delay of D degrees you can simply use the known Fourier transform below:

$$ F\left \{ f(t-\theta) \right \} \rightarrow \hat{f}(w) \times e^{jw\theta} $$

Assuming that your sound is a number of sinusoids added together; to apply same phase delay to all frequency components is multiply a complex number $ e^{jw\theta} $ where $\theta$ is your desired phase delay.

On the other hand if you want to apply the same time delay to all your frequency components you should calculate the appropriate phase angle shift to be applied to each frequency component. Assuming $t_{delay}$ is the delay you want to apply, you can obtain $\theta_w$ to apply with
$$ \theta_w = w\times t_{delay} = 2\pi f\times t_{delay} $$

In which, $\theta_w $ should be calculated for each frequency bin of your results of your DFT. And the reasoning behind this can be simply explained as below. Assume a signal with sinusoid components.
$$ f(t) = sin(2\pi f_1t) + sin(2\pi f_2t) $$
If I want to apply the same phase angle shift to both signals (I don't know why anyone would want but anyways):
$$ g(t) = sin(2\pi f_1t + \theta) + sin(2\pi f_2t + \theta) $$
And to apply a time delay:
$$ f(t-t_{delay}) = sin(2\pi f_1(t-t_{delay})) + sin(2\pi f_2(t-t_{delay})) $$
$$ f(t-t_{delay}) = sin(2\pi f_1t-2\pi f_1t_{delay}) + sin(2\pi f_2t-2\pi f_2t_{delay}) $$
As you see the phase angle shift $\theta$ you should apply is different for each frequency component.

edit: If you have the proper MATLAB license you could try checking out the doc and source of delayseq function (it's in Phased Array System Toolbox).

Comment: Of course! The Translation property of the Fourier Transform, I didn't think in that before. Thanks Alp Sayin for also pointing out that each component of the spectrum has to be multiplied by a diferent complex number, depending on the frequency.

Comment: I think the link for delayseq is this one: http://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/delayseq.html Thks again